# Gradle lock exception: Gradle in use by another Gradle instance

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am having a Gradle weird issue which does not seem to be related with me code. When I checked Jenkins, the build was broken with this exception:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.LockTimeoutException: Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for build file '/Users/me/IdeaProjects/api/explore/build.gradle' (/Users/me/.gradle/caches/2.2/scripts/build_dr53ryug2vbnxp25bu47jmb6a/ProjectScript/buildscript). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 10869
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: Initialize cache
Lock file: /Users/me/.gradle/caches/2.2/scripts/build_dr53ryug2vbnxp25bu47jmb6a/ProjectScript/buildscript/cache.properties.lock
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:258)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:127)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:80)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:99)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:46)
        ... 44 more
```

Any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to say, while there is no gradle script in question, but gradle has some similar issue https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2795

Answer (score 3):

> If you are having gradle version 4.1 and above

Here are possible reasons.

1. In a shared network, somebody has initiated a gradle build from your same `gradle home directory`. Now in your VM/machine, you are trying to run another build from the same direcory.

   **what happens here**

   The build and mapping cache files are locked by gradle by the previous run and now for your build, you are getting the `lockException`.

   **what can you do**

   Even if you kill all the gradle processes running on your machine, you cannot remove the lock. 
       `a. Go to the machine where you think another build has been triggered to stop the build`

   ```
   b. Clear all the .gradle/.cache and re-run the build.
   ```
2. Can also happen when the previous build not terminated properly and lock still exists.

Comment: You can stop Gradle daemon by running ` ./gradlew --stop`

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you run new build, but your previous build was suspended.
In order to fix this issue you have to remove *cache.properties.lock* file